# Why do I get fatal error C1075, I checked the code and nothing was wrong

Tags: visual-c++

I am an early C++ programmer and i wanted to create a simple little game on CMD with C++. Why do I get

> fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace and read and write files not working

I checked every line and nothing appeared wrong.

I checked every line and nothing appeared wrong. No 'curly' red line appeared to me on any character. Maybe my eyes are wrong.

```cpp
std::cout << "Enter 1 to Play: ";
int play = 0;
std::cin >> play;

if (play == 1) {
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << "                          +=======================================+\n";
  std::cout << "                          ||            CMD Math Tester          ||\n";
  std::cout << "                          ||              Version 1.0            ||\n";
  std::cout << "                          ++-------------------------------------++\n";
  std::cout << "                          ||         Answer the questions.       ||\n";
  std::cout << "                          +=======================================+\n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << " \n";
  std::cout << "What is 2+2: ";
  int answerExpected = 4;
  int answerOfUser = 0;
  std::cin >> answerOfUser;
  if (answerOfUser == answerExpected) {
    std::cout << "That is correct!\n";
    std::cout << " \n";
    std::cout << "What is 10+11: ";
    answerExpected = 21;
    answerOfUser = 0;
    std::cin >> answerOfUser;
    if (answerOfUser == answerExpected) {
      std::cout << "That is correct!\n";
      std::cout << " \n";
      std::cout << "What is 100+200: ";
      answerExpected = 300;
      answerOfUser = 0;
      std::cin >> answerOfUser;
      if (answerOfUser == answerExpected) {
        std::cout << "That is correct!\n";
        std::cout << " \n";
        std::cout << "What is 500-250: ";
        answerExpected = 250;
        answerOfUser = 0;
        std::cin >> answerOfUser;
        if (answerOfUser = answerExpected) {
          std::cout << "That is correct!\n";
          std::cout << " \n";
          std::cout << "What is 5*2: ";
          answerExpected = 10;
          answerOfUser = 0;
          std::cin >> answerOfUser;
          if (answerOfUser == answerExpected) {
            std::cout << "That is correct!\n";
            std::cout << " \n";
            std::cout << "What is 5*5: ";
            answerExpected = 25;
            answerOfUser = 0;
            std::cin >> answerOfUser;
            if (answerOfUser == answerExpected) {
              std::cout << "That is correct!\n";
              std::cout << " \n";
              std::cout << "What is 200*5: ";
              answerExpected = 1000;
              answerOfUser = 0;
              std::cin >> answerOfUser;
              if (answerOfUser == answerExpected) {
                std::cout << "That is correct!\n";
                std::cout << " \n";
                std::cout << "What is the sqrt of 16: ";
                answerExpected = 4;
                answerOfUser = 0;
                std::cin >> answerOfUser;
                if (answerOfUser == answerExpected) {
                  std::cout << "That is correct!\n";
                  std::cout << " \n";
                  std::cout << "What is the sqrt of 81: ";
                  answerExpected = 9;
                  answerOfUser = 0;
                  std::cin >> answerOfUser;
                  if (answerOfUser == answerExpected) {
                    std::cout << "That is correct!\n";
                    std::cout << " \n";
                    std::cout << "What is the absolute of 420: ";
                    answerExpected = 420;
                    answerOfUser = 0;
                    std::cin >> answerOfUser;
                    if (answerOfUser == answerExpected) {
                      std::cout << "That is correct!\n";
                      std::cout << " \n";
                      std::cout << "What is the absolute of -639: ";
                      answerExpected = 639;
                      answerOfUser = 0;
                      std::cin >> answerOfUser;
                      if (answerOfUser == answerExpected) {
                        std::cout << "+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+\n";
                        std::cout << "|       Congratulations       |\n";
                        std::cout << "+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+\n";
                        std::cout << " \n";
                        std::cout << " \n";
                        std::cout << "You Have passed the test!\n";
                      } else {
                        std::cout << "That is wrong.\n";
                      }
                    } else {
                      std::cout << "That is wrong.\n";
                    }
                  } else {
                    std::cout << "That is wrong.\n";
                  }
                } else {
                  std::cout << "That is wrong.\n";
                }
              } else {
                std::cout << "That is wrong.\n";
              }
            } else {
              std::cout << "That is wrong.\n";
            }
          } else {
            std::cout << "That is wrong.\n";
          }
        } else {
          std::cout << "That is wrong.\n";
        }
      } else {
        std::cout << "That is wrong.\n";
      }
    } else {
      std::cout << "That is wrong.\n";
    }
  } else {
    std::cout << "Enter 1 to Play: ";
    std::cin >> play;
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace and read and write files not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672495/fatal-error-c1075-end-of-file-found-before-the-left-brace-and-read-and-write-fi)

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 1):

If you take the complete error message, you will get something like

> fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace and read and write files not working

That mean that you don't close enough block that you open them (there is more `{` than `}`).

To correct the problem, you should indent you code source better.

Some tools like [`indent`](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) will do it for you. You can even find some tools [online](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_c_formatter.htm).

---

But there is other problems in your code:

- there is no `main`
- includes are missing
- `if (answerOfUser = answerExpected)` (`=` instead of `==` on 4th question) is not what you want

---

That said, it would be far easier to split your code into different functions to improve readability.

Since your game is to ask a series of questions, you could start by one function by question... But this point of discussion has its place more on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/